# How to fix a cistern float that jams

Tags: plumbing, toilet, plumbing-fixture, cistern

The float in the image is in a cistern. Sometimes it jams right at the top so the water keeps on filling and doesn't stop. Is there a way to lubricate or fix this type of float to prevent it from jamming in the last quarter inch?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new fill valve costs about $10, so it's probably more cost effective to simply replace it.

## Procedure

[image: Toilet supply]

- Turn off the water to the toilet using the shutoff valve
- Hold the flush lever on the toilet down (not pictured), until nearly all the water has drained from the tank.
- Remove the supply line from the fill valve, by turning the nut anticlockwise.
- Place a bucket under the fill valve (where you just removed the supply line from).
- Remove the retaining nut from the fill valve, by turning it anticlockwise.

[image: toilet tank]

- Remove the refill tube from the overflow tube.
- Lift the fill valve out of the tank.

## Installation

- Follow the installation instructions included with the new fill valve.